# Combining all of the node_modules packages' LICENSE files into one file

Tags: node.js, npm

In my node_modules folder, let's say that I have 5 folders:

Folder1

Folder2

Folder3

Folder4

Folder5

Each folder contains a "LICENSE" file or "LICENSE.md" file. I want to run a script of some kind whether it be Python or JS that takes the contents of each LICENSE file along with name of package and add it to one single file "Destination.txt". Is there an easier way to do this? I know that NPM License Checker allows me to list licenses and then I can output the results into a text file, but I also want to see the contents of each LICENSE file into a single file.

So sample output for Destination.txt should be like:

Folder1

text from LICENSE file

Folder2

text from LICENSE file

Folder3

text from LICENSE file

Folder4

text from LICENSE file

Folder5

text from LICENSE file

What I'm thinking about is possibly a Python script that traverses each folder in node_modules and tries to find a LICENSE file. When it goes into a folder and finds a LICENSE, it copies / pastes the contents into Destination.txt and then moves on to the next LICENSE file. I'm not sure how to implement this and would appreciate any tips. Doesn't have to be Python. I'm on a Windows computer so if there's a creative way to use the CLI commands to generate what I'm looking for, that'd be great.

**TLDR; I want to list the names of my packages as well as the contents of their associated LICENSE files all in one file. So if package1 is listed, the contents of the package1 LICENSE file will be listed below it. Same with package2 and so on.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The closest thing I've been able to find that doesn't require a custom script is [Yarn Licenses](https://classic.yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/licenses/).

I used command `yarn licenses generate-disclaimer > output.txt`

It worked even though I have never installed anything via Yarn before. Only NPM.

Answer (score 0):

most languages has a package that already does that. e.g.

**nodejs:**

- [legally](https://www.npmjs.com/package/legally)
- [license-checker](https://www.npmjs.com/package/license-checker)

**python:**

- [pip licenses](https://pypi.org/project/pip-licenses/)

**ruby:**

- [bundle-audit](https://github.com/stewartmckee/bundle-audit)

each of which has ability to produce a json file, which you can then parse and combine as you wish.

if you specifically interested in npm packages, then just use [`npm view`](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v6/commands/npm-view) like so

```sh
$ npm view eslint --json license
"MIT"
```

and if you want it to all your npm packages, then you can combine it with `npm ls` like so

```sh
for PKG in $(npm ls --json | jq -r '.dependencies | keys | .[]')
do
  npm view $PKG name license --json
done
```

Comment: I didn't know about legally, but I'm finding it more useful than license-checker. However, I'm still confused about how to get the actual license text to show up. What I want is a destination.txt file that contains a list of names of my packages and then underneath each package I want there to be the text from the associated LICENSE file to be included. I don't just want a list of packages.

Comment: i think my answer covers it :)

Comment: I'm confused. I believe your answer gives me package name and license type (e.g. "MIT"). That is not what I'm looking for. I'm looking for package name and full license text which is paragraphs. Let me know if I am missing something.

Comment: @JoffreyBaratheon this is a surprisingly hard thing to find, as I am also discovering :)

Answer (score 0):

The [generate-license-file](https://www.npmjs.com/package/generate-license-file) package does exactly what you need:

```
% npx generate-license-file --input package.json --output 3rd-party.txt
% cat 3rd-party.txt
This file was generated with the generate-license-file npm package!
https://www.npmjs.com/package/generate-license-file

The following npm package may be included in this product:

 - @babel/runtime@7.22.10

This package contains the following license and notice below:

MIT License

Copyright (c) 2014-present Sebastian McKenzie and other contributors

Permission is hereby granted, free of charge, to any person obtaining
a copy of this software and associated documentation files (the
"Software"), to deal in the Software without restriction, including
without limitation the rights to use, copy, modify, merge, publish,
distribute, sublicense, and/or sell copies of the Software, and to
permit persons to whom the Software is furnished to do so, subject to
the following conditions:

The above copyright notice and this permission notice shall be
included in all copies or substantial portions of the Software.

THE SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED "AS IS", WITHOUT WARRANTY OF ANY KIND,
EXPRESS OR IMPLIED, INCLUDING BUT NOT LIMITED TO THE WARRANTIES OF
MERCHANTABILITY, FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE AND
NONINFRINGEMENT. IN NO EVENT SHALL THE AUTHORS OR COPYRIGHT HOLDERS BE
LIABLE FOR ANY CLAIM, DAMAGES OR OTHER LIABILITY, WHETHER IN AN ACTION
OF CONTRACT, TORT OR OTHERWISE, ARISING FROM, OUT OF OR IN CONNECTION
WITH THE SOFTWARE OR THE USE OR OTHER DEALINGS IN THE SOFTWARE.

-----------

The following npm packages may be included in this product:

 - @floating-ui/core@1.4.1
 - @floating-ui/dom@1.5.1
 - @floating-ui/utils@0.1.1

These packages each contain the following license and notice below:

MIT License
```